# Question about ubuntu gcc compiler

Tags: c, gcc, ubuntu, compilation, gcc3

I installed the build-essential package for ubuntu x86_64, compiling c programs and c++ programs work fine, but in the compiled binary, "Ubuntu linaro" appears. is there a way to remove this?

Comment: Really? I thought they were an ARM mob, not x86. In any case, do you really _care_ what strings are in the binary, as long as it works okay?

Comment: Usually no, but if i'm compiling commercial software, i don't want people to know it was compiled using ubuntu

Comment: By people, you mean you don't want the guys who will open the binary in a hex editor to know that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can figure out what section that string is in (.comment maybe?) you can use

```
strip -R .comment (or whatever section name)
```

to remove that section from the binary.

gcc on Ubuntu 10.10 for x86 doesn't seem to put any extraneous strings in the binaries.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove it using a hex editor. And may i ask why do you want to remove it??

Comment: If i'm compiling commercial software, i don't want people to know it was compiled using ubuntu